# Método split() javascript num Array

Tags: javascript, front-end

Como conseguir o mesmo resultado da **variável** abaixo no **array**?

```js
// Variável
var str = "How are you doing today?";
var res = str.split(" ", 3);
document.write(res)

// Array
var str = ["How are you doing today?"];
var res = str.split(" ", 3);
document.write(res)
```

Comment: faca um loop do `str` e voce consegue dar um split... `str[i].split(" ", 3)`

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Utilizando for
var phrases = ["How are you doing today?", "I am great"];
for (var index in phrases) {
  console.log(phrases[index].split(" ", 3));
}

// Utilizando map
phrases = ["How are you doing today?", "I am great"];
var results = phrases.map(function(element, index, array) {
  return element.split(" ", 3);
});

console.log(results);
console.log(results[0]);
console.log(results[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Consegui assim:

```js
// Variável
var str = "How are you doing today?";
var res = str.split(" ", 3);
console.log(res)

// Array
var str = ["How are you doing today?"];
for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
 var res = str[i].split(" ", 3)
console.log(res)
}
```